# Make Math.Random loop until specific number is reached

Tags: java, math, random, dice

I'm trying to make a program that 'rolls two dice' and combines the number and needs to keep going until  a specific number is reached 7 or 11 but every time I run it it keeps going forever.

```
double total = 0;
while (total != 7 || total != 11) {
    DecimalFormat x = new DecimalFormat("#");
    double dice1 = Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    double dice2 = Math.random() * 6 + 1;
    double total = (dice1 + dice2);
    System.out.println("Dice 1: " + x.format(dice1) + " Dice 2: " + x.format(dice2) + " Total: " + x.format(total));

    }
```

I think its because the int total is set to 0 and isn't getting the total from the loop but how can i fix this?

Comment: This code should have a compiler error: variable `total` is already defined in this scope.

Comment: This is a case where stepping through with a debugger would do you a world of good!

Answer (score 5):

Your `while` loop logic is not correct.  The total will always not be `7` or not be `11`.  You want "and" instead, using `&&`.  Change

```
while (total != 7 || total != 11) {
```

to

```
while (total != 7 && total != 11) {
```

Also, I don't know of any dice that yield non-integers, so I would cast the results to `int` and declare `dice1`, `dice2`, and `total` as `int`s.

Answer (score 4):

It's because you shadow `total` and you need to test logical and (not or). I would also prefer to use [`Random`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) and [`nextInt(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29) like

```
int total = 0; // <-- don't shadow me.
Random rand = new Random(); 
while (total != 7 && total != 11) {
  int dice1 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1; // <-- using rand.
  int dice2 = rand.nextInt(6) + 1;
  total = (dice1 + dice2); // <-- no double.
  System.out.printf("Dice 1: %d Dice 2: %d Total: %d%n", dice1, dice2, total);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I didn't know why i was using double, and im guessing when it was double it was an absolute value?

Comment: No, you were shadowing (or hiding) the `total`. Basically, the `total` in your loop was a different variable named `total`.

Comment: @TajMelic When you used `double` it was generating numbers with decimal fractions.  The sum was *never* going to be exactly equal to 7 or 11, even had you fixed the shadowing problem and the logical OR problem.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch thanks for clearing this up. It makes more sense now. Also thats probably the reason i had to user DecimalFormat to get rid of the fractions.

Comment: @TajMelic You should probably move that `DecimalFormat` outside your loop in addition to the various other fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You need an AND instead of an OR. And try it with int:

```
int total = 0;
    while (total != 7 && total != 11) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int dice1 =  rand.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        int dice2 =  rand.nextInt((6 - 1) + 1) + 1;
        total = (dice1 + dice2);
        System.out.println("Dice 1: " + dice1 + " Dice 2: " +dice2 + " Total: " + total);
```